# How to add an item to a ListView with each Button click

Tags: java, android, android-listview, android-button

This is the code I'm working on, it should simply add an item in a ListView (w/ array) each time the Button is clicked. The text inserted by the user on a EditText should be added to the list each time the Button is clicked.

I find that this line of code:

```
new Button.OnClickListener()
```

is seen as an 'anonymous' thing, and it's not run, please help me out ;(

```
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.*;
import android.widget.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
//Setup Lists
String[] arrayNames;
ListView listNames;
TextView namesText;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //Creating and Printing Lists
    listNames = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listNamesId);
    namesText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.namesTexter);
    final ArrayAdapter<String> adapterNames = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, (List<String>) namesText);

    Button buttonPlus = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonPlus);
    buttonPlus.setOnClickListener(
            new Button.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    listNames.setAdapter(adapterNames);
                }
            }
    );
}
```

XML

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity">


<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listNamesId"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:divider="#000"
    android:dividerHeight="1dp"
    android:headerDividersEnabled="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"></ListView>

<Button
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/textnametextname"
    android:id="@+id/buttonPlus"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/namesTexter"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/buttonPlus"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:inputType="text" />
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem?  Is this a compile error or a runtime error?

Comment: can you provide the error, or explain what happens?

Comment: It should be a runtime error, but I think it's just something wrong in my code, I guess the issue is I'm trying to pass the value of `namesText` into a list, but that value is a TextView type, so it wouldn't allow me to insert it on an array adapter, that's why I did take the hint to add that `(List<String>) namesText` which is (for me) the real error @ Daniel Nugent

Comment: That's it @JasonPortnoy, I think the error is to find a way to pass the value of namesText in that adapter

Comment: You say its not being called? Can you show your activity_main xml

Comment: Sure, gonna edit my question with the XML

Comment: I think the problem is the parameters you pass to the `ArrayAdapter` constructor.

Comment: Yes @Titus ! I think the same, but how to solve it?

Comment: Try: `new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arrayNames)` but you should instantiate `arrayNames` first.

Comment: I don't know how to continue then :/ @Titus

Comment: ** If it's needed, you can even (almost) completely change the code, if in that way it will be more efficient and better looking  **

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not with your button click listener, it's that you're not using a List as the data source of your Adapter.

I just got this working using an ArrayList as the data source, and updating it in the button click listener. Each time you click the button, whatever is in the EditText gets added to the ListView.

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    ArrayList<String> arrayNames = new ArrayList<String>();
    ListView listNames;
    TextView namesText;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        //Creating and Printing Lists
        listNames = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listNamesId);
        namesText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.namesTexter);
        final ArrayAdapter<String> adapterNames = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, arrayNames);
        listNames.setAdapter(adapterNames);

        Button buttonPlus = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonPlus);

        buttonPlus.setOnClickListener(
                new Button.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        arrayNames.add(0, namesText.getText().toString());
                        adapterNames.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        namesText.setText("");

                    }
                }
        );


    }
```

Comment: Yes. This is what I meant. It works. But not entirely: when I add it a part that the text area should be cleared (but that's not a problem for me though) it needs to be possible to display more than 1 only item, if you test this code (masteripiece ;) ) I can only add a max of 1 item, instead every time I click enter it should add one more item

Comment: Hope I've explained the concept of it good enough @Daniel Nugent ;)

Comment: Thanks, maybe I have mistaken on updating mine, I'll wait for ya ;)

Comment: You're awesome @Daniel Nugent ;) But, one more question to not let you go so early.. how do tell the app to add the item at the top instead of at the bottom?

Comment: @InssideYou Just updated the answer again, just use `arrayNames.add(0, namesText.getText().toString());`.  This will add each item to the start of the list instead of adding to the end!

Comment: I think is more simple to add the propery `android:stackFromBottom="true"` 
 to the Listview (in XML file)

Comment: @Joseph82 Yeah, that would work too.  I suppose it depends on how he wants the data ordered in the data source.  Looks like we came up with almost identical answers minutes appart, haha....  Great minds think alike! :)

Comment: Yeap thanks to both of you! By the way I suppose that 0 is to make it append at the top and 1 at the bottom? By the way if that's not too much may I ask you your email or a way to contact you again if I'll have another problem with my app? :D

Comment: @InssideYou  Actually the `0` is the index to add to the list.  If you use the original version with just the parameter to add, it adds it to the end of the list.   If you need help in the future, just post a question here on SO and ping me in the comments of this post, and I'll take a look!  Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

In order to achive what you want, it seems without sense set the adapter inside the onclick. What you should do is to add an item inside the `onClick()` method, and then call the method `notifyDataSetChanged()` on the adapter, for ensuring that the new data are displayed.

This is the code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final ListView listNames = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listNamesId);
    final TextView namesText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.namesTexter);
    final ArrayAdapter<String> adapterNames = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, new ArrayList<String>());
    listNames.setAdapter(adapterNames);

    Button buttonPlus = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonPlus);
    buttonPlus.setOnClickListener(
        new Button.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(!namesText.getText().toString().isEmpty()){
                     adapterNames.add(namesText.getText().toString());
                     namesText.setText("");
                     adapterNames.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }

            }
        }
    );
```

}

Comment: Yes it works, but it doesn't clear the text area :P By the way absolutely yes, this is what I was looking for

Comment: @InssideYou try now! ;) It also check for empty string.

Comment: Yes! It works, thanks a lot @Joseph82! But now I'm trying to figure out how to add the item on the top instead of the bottom..

Comment: Inside your xml add `android:stackFromBottom="true"` to your ListView

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
public void onMyButtonClick(View view){
        listNames.setAdapter(adapterNames);    
}
```

And in your xlm file

```
<Button>
 .....
android:onclick="onMyButtonClick"
....
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Error:(21) No resource identifier found for attribute 'onclick' in package 'android'

Comment: is `android:onClick="onMyButtonClick"`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like namesText is a TextView. But its being cast as a List in the next line.

```
namesText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.namesTexter);


final ArrayAdapter<String> adapterNames = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, (List<String>) namesText);
```