# How to add multiple item to a ListView with each Button click

Tags: java, android

I found much on google but not able to get the answer.
I got [How to add an item to a ListView with each Button click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31279216/how-to-add-an-item-to-a-listview-with-each-button-click). 
here we are learning to add single item..
thanks in advance

Comment: I suggest you look into [RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview.html) as it is a better version of `ListView`

Answer (score 0):

Any reason why you can't try the following?

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    myDataArray.add(data1);
    myDataArray.add(data2);
    myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Comment: can u please explain bit more,,
I want to populate the data (4 fields) in custom listview each time after "add button" is clicked 
the data will be taken from EditText

Answer (score 0):

Just like in the answer provided in the question you've shared, to add two items -

1) add both the data to the array

2) notify data set changes

```
// Add the data fields to the array
dataArray.add(0, dataField1);
dataArray.add(1, dataField2);
// Notify the adapter that data set has changed
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Try `dataArray.add(dataField)` inside the button's `onClick` and notify the adapter about the changes. Every time the button is clicked, an item gets added at the end of the list.

Comment: I want to populate the data (4 fields)  in custom listview each time after "add button" is clicked 
the data will be taken from EditText

Comment: So, you want to add one data object (to the list) evertime the user has clicked the add button? Do you've a specific position that you want to add or you want to add the data at the end of the list?

Comment: the data will add at the end of the list..
btu user can delete any data (i.e, data at any potion) of the list

Answer (score 0):

**So if you want to do this statically**

```
ListView<String> list = new ListView<String>();
    ObservableList<String> items = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
            "something1", "something2", "something3");
    list.setItems(items);
```

**But if you want to do this dinamically  you can use this code:**

```
ListView<String> list = new ListView<String>();
    ObservableList<String> items = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
            "something1", "something2", "something3");
    list.setItems(items);

 list.setEditable(true);

    Button btn = new Button();
    btn.setText("Add String");
    btn.setOnAction((ActionEvent event) -> {
        list.getItems().add(i - 1, "something" + i);
        list.edit(i - 2);
        i++;
    });
```